# How to display the tooltip in exact location with in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table were the row is being looped and and for some instance I want to hover the mouse of one of its **tr** under the **td** with a **class="updeltd"** and display a **div element as its tooltip**. My problem is when I hover the mouse on that td I can only be able to display my tooltip on the first row of the table instead of the row where I put the mouse. I think I have a problem on my javascript function. Here's the details, Thanks...

**jQuery/Javascript function:**

```
function DispTooltip() {

           var ttipshow = document.getElementById("tooltip");
           ttipshow.style.display = "block";

           var coord = $(this).closest('table').find('td[class="updeltd"]').offset();

           $('#tooltip').css({ top: coord.top, left: coord.left - 345 });

        }
```

**Tooltip:**

```
<div id="tooltip"> This is my tooltip </div>
```

**HTML View:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nationality)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr >
        <td id="ID">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td id="Name">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td id="Addr">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td id="age">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td id="occ">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Occupation)
        </td>

        <td id="natn">
              <input type="text" id="nat" value="  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nationality)" style="display:none" />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nationality)
        </td>

       <td id="image" onmouseover="DispTooltip()" onmouseout="return HideTooltip();">
       <img id="detimg" alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Photos/" + item.Photos)" style="width:50px;height:50px" />

        </td>

       <td id="updel" class="updeltd" onmouseover="DispTooltip()" onmouseout="return HideTooltip();" >

      @Html.ActionLink("Edit/Delete Records", "UpdateDeleteRec", new { id=item.ID}) 

       </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Try to get the index of the tr and use it to mulitply with tr height and generate the tooltip position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you currently doing is finding the closest table element then finding all the `class="updeltd"` elements so `.offset()` returns the offset of the first one (the first row). What you need is

```
var coord = $(this).closest('tr').children('.updeltd').offset();
```

Note you are also creating invalid html by duplicating id's for each `td` element. Use class names instead

Comment: Same output,no changes at all I got the correct left coordinate already but i think the top coordinate is wrong coz the div element would always stays at the first row instead of the row being pointed. Do I need to change all the td ids into different class names?

Comment: As for the invalid html, each row has `<td id="ID">` which is invalid, so better to use `<td class="ID">`.

Comment: Do we need to set a class name for tr too? coz tr is duplicated as its being looped I think. Using this line var coord = $(this).closest('tr').children('.updeltd').offset(); the closest 'tr' is not specified because it has no class name. What do you think?

Comment: The `tr` does not necessarily need a class name . Just did a quick test in my project and `.offset()` works fine. After `var coord ..` add `console.log(coord.top); and test. Note I used $(tr').mouseenter(function() { ....` rather than `onmouseover="DispTooltip()"` in the `img` tag

Comment: Thanks, the function should be $('tr').mouseenter(function() {...}); instead of onmouseover, that was more accurate.